# Ant Report getting following error TestNG in another machine. But same code is working in my machine.. Did i missed anything here?

Tags: java, selenium, ant, testng

Ant Report getting following error TestNG in another machine. But same code is working in my machine.. Did i missed anything here?

`Failed to invoke configuration method`

`Test.Suite1.testing.Inti:Unable to get browser`

```
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   [testng] Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
   [testng] Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
   [testng] System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1',java.version: '1.7.0_55'
   [testng] Session ID: f9d60bfe-1eb2-411c-809b-3124f9ef2e2d[testng] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver [testng] Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://www.someport.com/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
   [testng] [Invoker 17510567] Keeping method testing.setBrowser()[pri:0, instance:Test.Suite1.testing@1f676cb] for class [TestClass name=classTest.Suite1.testing]
   [testng] [Invoker 17510567] Keeping method testing.setBrowser()[pri:0, instance:Test.Suite1.testing@1f676cb] for class [TestClass name=class Test.Suite1.testing]
   [testng] [Invoker 17510567] Keeping method testing.setBrowser()[pri:0, instance:Test.Suite1.testing@1f676cb] for class [TestClass name=class Test.Suite1.testing]
   [testng] [Invoker 17510567] Keeping method testing.closeBrowser()[pri:0, instance:Test.Suite1.testing@1f676cb] for class null
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be testng issue.  Have you set the iedriver property for the other machine?

Comment: Yes i used below code DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities
    .internetExplorer();
  capabilities
    .setCapability(
      InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
      true);
  File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
    + "//BrowserExe//IEDriverServer.exe");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);